# Display iPhone local notification in Apple Watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch, xcode-6.2

I'm trying to display local notifications in Apple Watch.

The implementation is done but I don't know how to pass local notifications to Apple Watch. How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your iOS app supports local or remote notifications, Apple Watch displays those notifications at appropriate times.

iOS it self decide to pass the notification to Apple Watch or show on iPhone,

As you said the implementation is done so let the iOS handle it. and at this time you have to do nothing to pass it to Watch **you can see the Apple documentation for more clarification.**

[You can see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)

Comment: @chirag,please explain in deep

Comment: anyone find something more specific than "appropriate times"?  all i found in apple doc was "appropriate times".

Answer (score 2):

iOS takes care of notifications.
If your iPhone is unlocked, you get notifications on your iPhone, instead of your Apple Watch.

If your iPhone is locked or asleep, and your Apple Watch is unlocked and on your wrist, you get notifications on your Apple Watch.

Read this
https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204791