# How to send push notification in Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I just configured WatchKit in my Project, in iPhone devices Push notification working properly, currently my requirement is send Push notification in Watch also through server...

Currently what I have tried is getting Notification from payload (static), I want to do it from server, can anyone help me out?

```
- (void)didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)remoteNotification withCompletion:(void(^)(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType interface)) completionHandler {

       NSDictionary* apsDict = [remoteNotification objectForKey:apsKeyString];

       NSString* titleString = [apsDict objectForKey:titleKeyString];
       [self.titleLabel setText:titleString];

       completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> When one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on the Apple Watch.

So you don't need to worry about to send notification on Watch, iOS will do it for you

Here is the [Answer, I already Posted about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832911/display-iphone-local-notification-in-apple-watch/28833157#28833157).

This thread contains `Apple Watch Notification Essentials` Helping Link by `Apple` too.

And yes this is the method you are using (posted in question) to listen push notification in Watch

Comment: If in iPhone push notification configured then in Apple watch it automatically get's the Notification`(didReceiveRemoteNotification)` ?

Comment: yes you are right. but notification will only be in one device either in iPhone or in Apple Watch. and iOS decide it itself where to send notification.

Comment: what about together if we send one simple push to device then it receives either iPhone or Apple watch ? what about for both ?

Comment: no it is not an efficient way. and iOS does not allow it as well. Why you are going to send the same thing on both devices. user will bother on any device if this will be his/her interest.

Comment: @Panther , alright...!!! then you should write to Apple to let this happen in your case because this is not the way to prompt the same thing on both devices.

Comment: These are the words written in Apple Watch Programming Guide. `iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on the Apple Watch` not you.

Comment: Hello Friends i use Notification service extension in iPhone to display Notification and I download image manually and assign to UIImageView

Let, I want to know How I do similar things happen for Apple Watchkit Push Notification Means When iOS send notification to watch How I dowanload image for Watch and assign to UIImageView

Comment: @M Zubair Shamshad

Hello Friends i use Notification service extension in iPhone to display Notification and I download image manually and assign to UIImageView

Let, I want to know How I do similar things happen for Apple Watchkit Push Notification. Means, When iOS send notification to watch How I download image for Watch and assign to UIImageView